# Powershell variable export-CSV cache?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, export-to-csv

I am working on a script by Richard L. Mueller (http://www.rlmueller.net/PowerShell/PSLastLogon.txt)

```
Trap {"Error: $_"; Break;}

$D = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
$Domain = [ADSI]"LDAP://$D"
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$Searcher.PageSize = 200
$Searcher.SearchScope = "subtree"

$Searcher.Filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user))"
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName") > $Null
$Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("lastLogon") > $Null

$arrUsers = @{}


ForEach ($DC In $D.DomainControllers)
{
$Server = $DC.Name
$Searcher.SearchRoot = "LDAP://$Server/" + $Domain.distinguishedName
$Results = $Searcher.FindAll()
ForEach ($Result In $Results)
{
    $DN = $Result.Properties.Item("samAccountName")
    $LL = $Result.Properties.Item("lastLogon")
    If ($LL.Count -eq 0)
    {
        $Last = [DateTime]0
    }
    Else
    {
        $Last = [DateTime]$LL.Item(0)
    }
    If ($Last -eq 0)
    {
        $LastLogon = $Last.AddYears(1600)
    }
    Else
    {
        $LastLogon = $Last.AddYears(1600).ToLocalTime()
    }
    If ($arrUsers.ContainsKey("$DN"))
    {
        If ($LastLogon -gt $arrUsers["$DN"])
        {
            $arrUsers["$DN"] = $LastLogon
        }
    }
    Else
    {
        $arrUsers.Add("$DN", $LastLogon)
    }
}
}


$inactiveusers = @()
$Users = $arrUsers.Keys
ForEach ($DN In $Users)
{
$Date = $arrUsers["$DN"]
"$DN;$Date"
$inactiveusers += $DN
$inactiveusers += $Date
$inactiveusers | export-csv "c:\test.csv"
}
```

Thinking to store the info to another array, I added the those line start with $inactiveusers (total of 4 lines). However the CSV exported does not gives me the correct result, instead of listing the user samAccountName & lastlogon, the length of the samAccountName is returned.

Further to this, since then I cannot export the same variable in my another script even the script is just simple as:

```
$inactiveusers = "Test"
$inactiveusers | Export-Csv c:\test.csv
write-host $inactiveusers
```

The CSV exported still give me the length of the string "Test", **however the write-host result is correct.**
I tried remove-variable, logoff & login back but both without luck.
I am not sure where the cache stored. I can work on the script later on but first I want to able to export this variable to CSV in another script. 
 appreciate anyone can give me some hint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Export-Csv`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176825.aspx) cmdlet does not export strings. It exports the properties of objects as fields of the output CSV file. In case of string objects, the exported property is the length of the string. You need to transform the hashtable into a list of custom objects to make the export work as you expect:

```
$arrUsers.Keys | % {
  New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
    'sAMAccountName' = $_
    'lastLogon'      = $arrUsers[$_]
  }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\test.csv' -NoType
```

Also the manual date calculation could be replaced with the [`FromFileTime()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromfiletime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
$lastLogon = [DateTime]::FromFileTime($Result.Properties.Item("lastLogon"))
```

With that said, why are you doing this "by hand" in the first place? The `ActiveDirectory` PowerShell module has a cmdlet `Get-ADUser` that already does all the work for you:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties * | ? {
  $_.LastLogonDate -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)
} | select SamAccountName, LastLogonDate | Export-Csv 'C:\test.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: Hi @AnsgarWiechers, My goal is to disable users which inactive for >30 days. I actually have another script which Get-QADUser&use LastLogonTimeStamp instead, but the problem with this is there is a delay&randomization it get updated, which the randomization is not allowed in our policy. Reducing the delay will increase the AD replication load & I try to avoid that by looking into LastLogon instead. However understand that LastLogon does not replicate between servers therefore I use Richard Mueller's script above to compare all servers. Understood on the Export-CSV & I will study on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why move all the items from `$arrUsers` to `$inactiveusers`? You can achieve desired result by adding this at the very end:

```powershell
$arrUsers.getEnumerator() | Select-Object Key,Value | 
   Export-Csv c:\test.csv  -NoTypeInformation
```

Find out more about `Export-CSV`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849932.aspx

Comment: Hi Raf, thanks for the reply. However I actually have more tasks to do on the result (e.g. get the last logon date and compare with currently date to see how long time user has been inactive).

Comment: Then go with @Ansgar's solution, it lets you create objects, add as many properties as you need and can be exported via `Export-CSV`

Comment: Hi @Raf, actually with your script I already able to store the data into variable by: $inactiveusers = $arrUsers.getEnumerator() | Select-Object Key,Value. (I wanted to update in my previous comments but I mistakenly hit Enter and I forgot to edit it). I export-csv at here just to cross check the script is running well until that line, not really is my end result. Thanks & I will see how I can make use of the information stored.