# How do I calculate average ping response time in Powershell using Test-Connection?

Tags: powershell, average

I am new to PS scripting. I am in need of help with my code. 
purpose: ping a list of IP's from a .txt file and output the result in csv format. Here is my code thus far.

```
$Iplist = Get-Content ips.txt
$group = $()
foreach ($ip in $Iplist)
{
   $status = @{ "ServerIP Name" = $ip; "TimeStamp" = (Get-Date -f s) }
   if (Test-Connection $ip -Count 4 -ea 0 | measure-Object -Property ResponseTime -Average)
   {
        $status["Results"] = "Up"
   }
   else
   {
        $status["Results"] = "Down"
   }
   New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable serverStatus
   $group += $serverStatus
}
$group | export-csv c:\ping\results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What is the exact problem you're having?  Is the Csv not formatted correctly? Have you searched other questions? Here's a similar answer on how to export arrays/hashes to csv: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277632/powershell-variable-export-csv-cache

Comment: this actually works great as is, but my management is looking for it to display the average ping time (like 3 mil sec average) for each IP pinged. I am not currently getting this info. My output currently looks like this in the csv file: www.google.com 2014-08-12T16:38:25 Up   Does that make sense? I'm basically need to get that output from the average ping time to display in my csv file, right next to what currently displays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Test-Connection`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849808.aspx) returns a [`Win32_PingStatus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394350(v=vs.85).aspx) object.

To see what else is available on this object in PowerShell type:

```powershell
$ping = Test-Connection www.google.com #or insert favorite url here
$ping | Format-List | Out-String
```

`Test-Connection` doesn't just return a bool.  You're really close but you have to assign the return value in order to calculate the average on success:

```powershell
$Iplist = Get-Content ips.txt
$group = @()
foreach ($ip in $Iplist) {
  $status = @{ "ServerIP Name" = $ip; "TimeStamp" = (Get-Date -f s) }
  $pings = Test-Connection $ip -Count 4 -ea 0
  if ($pings) {
    $status["AverageResponseTime"] =
        ($pings | Measure-Object -Property ResponseTime -Average).Average
    $status["Results"] = "Up"
  }
  else {
    $status["Results"] = "Down"
  }

  New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable serverStatus
  $group += $serverStatus
}

$group | Export-Csv c:\ping\results.csv -NoTypeInformation
```